# Reading and writing non-standard floating point values

Tags: c#, floating-point, hex, byte, reverse-engineering

I'm working with a binary file (3d model file for an old video game) in C#. The file format isn't officially documented, but some of it has been reverse-engineered by the game's community.

I'm having trouble understanding how to read/write the 4-byte floating point values. I was provided this explanation by a member of the community:

> For example, the bytes `EE 62 ED FF` represent the value -18.614.
>
> The bytes are little endian ordered. The first 2 bytes represent the decimal part of the value, and the last 2 bytes represent the whole part of the value.
>
> For the decimal part, `62 EE` converted to decimal is 25326. This represents the fraction out of 1, which also can be described as 65536/65536. Thus, divide 25326 by 65536 and you'll get 0.386.
>
> For the whole part, `FF ED` converted to decimal is 65517. 65517 represents the whole number -19 (which is 65517 - 65536).
>
> This makes the value -19 + .386 = -18.614.

This explanation mostly makes sense, but I'm confused by 2 things:

1. Does the magic number 65536 have any significance?
2. `BinaryWriter.Write(-18.613f)` writes the bytes as `79 E9 94 C1`, so my assumption is the binary file I'm working with uses its own proprietary method of storing 4-byte floating point values (i.e. I can't use C#'s `float` interchangably and will need to encode/decode the values first)?

Comment: To start with that isn't a floating point value.

Comment: 65536=2^16... which can be significant yet arbitrary at the same time

Comment: also `25326 / 65536` isn't  `0.386`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this isn't a [Floating Point Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) its a [Fix Point Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic)

<sub>***Note*** : A fixed point number has a specific number of bits (or digits) reserved for the integer part (the part to the left of the decimal point)</sub>

> Does the magic number 65536 have any significance

Its the max number of values unsigned 16 bit number can hold, or `2^16`, yeah its significant, because the number you are working with is 2 * 16 bit values encoded for integral and fractional components.

> so my assumption is the binary file I'm working with uses its own
>   proprietary method of storing 4-byte floating point values

Nope wrong again, floating point values in .*Net* adhere to the [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754) technical standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

When you use `BinaryWriter.Write(float);` it basically just shifts the bits into `byte`s and writes it to the `Stream`.

```
uint TmpValue = *(uint *)&value;
_buffer[0] = (byte) TmpValue;
_buffer[1] = (byte) (TmpValue >> 8);
_buffer[2] = (byte) (TmpValue >> 16);
_buffer[3] = (byte) (TmpValue >> 24);
OutStream.Write(_buffer, 0, 4);
```

If you want to read and write this special value you will need to do the same thing, you are going to have to read and write the bytes and convert them your self

Comment: I don't think it's a `Fix Point Number` because it's `Last 2 bytes **adds*8 first 2 bytes`, not `All 4 bytes divided by 65536`. What do you think!?

Comment: @PiggyChu001 you are probably right that its not quite under the definition of a fix point value either

Comment: Glad you agree.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a build-in value unique to the game.

It should be more similar to `Fraction Value`.

Where `62 EE` represent the `Fraction Part` of the value and `FF ED` represent the `Whole Number Part` of the value.

The `While Number Part` is easy to understand so I'm not going to explain it.

The explanation of `Fraction Part` is:

For every 2 bytes, there are `65536` possibilities (0 ~ 65535).

> 256 X 256 = 65536

hence the magic number `65536`.

And the game itself must have a build-in algorithm to divide the first 2 bytes by 65536.

Choosing any number other than this will be a `waste of memory space` and result in `decreased accuracy of the value which can be represented`.

Of course, it's all depended on what kind of accuracy the game wish to present.